# Custom select in Angular not showing value of ngModel

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm quite new to angular (1), and have hit a problem.  I need a custom year picker in my app, that appears in several places.  The original code was

html

```
<select id="yearpicker" ng-model="vm.film.release" required="true" class="form-control">
     <option disabled="" selected="" value="">Choose one...  </option>
     <option disabled="">___________________</option>
     <option value="Unknown">Release Year Unknown</option>
     <option disabled="">___________________     </option>
 </select>
```

JS

```
<script>
    for (i = new Date().getFullYear(); i > 1900; i--)
    {
        $('#yearpicker').append($('<option />').val(i).html(i));
    };
</script>
```

Which gave me a nice dropdown with all the years from 1900 to present and a field for years where the year was unknown.  But, the code was on the page, which isn't very  nice, it meant that I had to load jquery before angular which was kicking out lots of errors, and also it meant that the code was repeated in several places.  I pulled the code out, and put it in a directive, so I didn't have to repeat it, and so I could load angular first and get rid of the errors.  Which I did like so

Directive JS

```
angular
.module('myapp')
.directive('customYearpicker', customYearpicker);

function customYearpicker () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
            bindModel: '=ngModel'
        },
        controller: function () {
            for (i = new Date().getFullYear(); i >= 1900; i--) {
                $('#yearpicker').append($('<option />').val(i).html(i));                    
            };
        },
        templateUrl: '/common/directives/customYearpicker/customYearpicker.template.html'
    };
};
```

html template

```
<select id="yearpicker" ng-model="bindModel" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Choose one...  </option>
    <option disabled="">___________________</option>
    <option value="Unknown">Release Year Unknown</option>
    <option disabled="">___________________     </option>    
</select>
```

and I'm calling it like so

```
<custom-yearpicker name="release" ng-model="vm.record.release" required="true"></custom-yearpicker>
```

This works fine everywhere, except where I want to edit the record, and now the select is no longer populated by the value in 'vm.record.release' and is just blank.  'vm.record.release' has the correct value, it is just not displayed in my drop down, but neither is "Choose one... ", as with all other instances. Apart from this the yearpicker works fine, but this needs fixing.

If anyone can point out the (most likely) glaringly obvious blunder I've made, or point me in the right direction if I'm doing it all wrong,  it would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

UPDATE

So after being advised to use ng-options, I have now updated my directive to this:

```
angular
.module('myapp')
.directive('customYearpicker', customYearpicker);

function customYearpicker () {

    return {
      restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
          bindModel: '=ngModel'
        },  
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.selectOptions = [
                { name: '', text: 'Choose one... ' },
                { name: '', text: '___________________' },
                { name: 'Unknown', text: 'Release Year Unknown' },
                { name: '', text: '___________________' },
             ];

            for (i = new Date().getFullYear(); i >= 1900; i--) {
                // $('#yearpicker').append($('<option />').val(i).html(i));  
                var newOpt = { name: i, text: i};
                $scope.selectOptions.push(newOpt);                  
              };

              console.log($scope.selectOptions);
              return $scope.selectOptions; 
        },          
        templateUrl: "/common/directives/customYearpicker/customYearpicker.template.html"
    };
  };
```

and the html template to this:

```
<select id="yearpicker" ng-model="bindModel" ng-options="option.name as option.text for option in selectOptions" class="form-control"> </select>
```

and I am calling it like this:

```
<custom-yearpicker name="release" ng-model="vm.record.release" required="true"></custom-yearpicker>
```

The problem is that even though it works much as before, my disabled options are no longer disabled, and the yearpicker is still not showing the value of vm.record.release.  If I pick a value from the selector it is picked up by the edit controller with no problems, it just isn't selected in the selector for some reason.  Still looking for suggestions please.

Comment: Can u share code for edit the record?

Answer (score 1):

When bootstrapping your app, you need to declare the dependencies. If there are none, just use an empty array.

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
app.directive('customYearpicker', customYearpicker);

function customYearpicker () {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
      scope: {
        bindModel: '=ngModel'
      },
      controller: function () {
        for (i = new Date().getFullYear(); i >= 1900; i--) {
          $('#yearpicker').append($('<option />').val(i).html(i));                    
        };
      },
      template: `<select id="yearpicker" ng-model="bindModel" class="form-control"><option value="">Choose one...  </option><option disabled="">___________________</option><option value="Unknown">Release Year Unknown</option><option disabled="">___________________     </option></select>`
  };
};
```

Notice I used `template` instead of `templateUrl` for expediency on my end, but your `templateUrl` should work.

Also, I should mention that this is not the Angular way of creating selects. Please [look into ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions).

Comment: I've changed the directive to use ng-options as advised.  the directive is now working, the same as it was before but the ngModel data is still not showing in the select box.  Any suggestions?

Comment: So you don't see the years populating as options on your select?

Comment: years are populating, and it works fine on other pages, it's just this one page where I already have a value for vm.record.result.  I want it to show as selected and be able to change it, but it seems to be creating a blank option and inserting it before all of the others and selecting that.  If that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use jQuery for such things.

directive code:

```
function customYearSelect(){
    return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      model: '=ngModel',
      name: '@',
      yearFrom: '@',
      yearTo: '@'
    },
    templateUrl: 'custom-year-select.template.html',
    link: function (scope,element,attr) {
      var yearFrom = attr['yearFrom'] ? attr['yearFrom'] : 1990;
      var yearTo = attr['yearTo'] ? attr['yearTo'] : new Date().getFullYear();      
      scope.yearArray = [];
        for(var i = yearTo; i >= yearFrom; i--){
        scope.yearArray.push(i);
      }
    }      
  }
}
```

template:

```
  <select name="custom-year-selet" ng-model="model" ng-options="name + ' ' + year for year in yearArray">
      <option name="selectYear" value="" style="display:none">-- select year --</option>
  </select>
```

HTML:

```
<custom-year-select name="Release year:" ng-model="selectedYear2"
    year-from="2000" year-to="2005"></custom-year-select>
```

Here's a working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kvda7Lc7/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. In the end it was just me being a bit dopey, the fix was:

```
for (i = new Date().getFullYear(); i >= 1900; i--) {
            // $('#yearpicker').append($('<option />').val(i).html(i));  
            var newOpt = { name: String(i), text: String(i) };
            $scope.selectOptions.push(newOpt);                  
          };
```

I just needed to parse the dates, doh!

Well thanks for the help anyway, I now have a directive doing it the angular way, instead of some bodgy jquery hack, and it all works .

Thanks for setting me on the right track Jorge.